# Export IIS Configuration

Tags: iis, configuration, export, iis-7.5, shared

I want export my IIS Configuration at IIS 7.5 over Shared Configuration.
I get an error message:
Export of configuration files failed.I have no entries at Eventlog, IIS or anything else.

I hope somebody can help me,

Horst

Answer (score 2):

This works form me:

- Stop IIS Server
- Delete all files under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
- Uncheck the shared configuration.

After this steps, I can export the configuration and also set the shared configuration again.

Horst

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD as Administrator and run:

- IISRESET -STOP
- Then move all files in
  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys to another folder
  except
  c2319c42033a5ca7f44e731bfd3fa2b5_5630a856-d018-483a-866a-3b9512d1e19e
- Then run: IISRESET -START

It should work fine